# How do op-amp output add to/substract from the input voltage in postive/negative feedback?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Unlike for current, I don't understand how voltages add up or cancel each other.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPcPdL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With negative feedback, Vout will try to make V- and V+ equal but 'taking away' or 'adding' voltage to the inverting input.

You have this essential equation for op-amp:
$$V_{out}=A_0(V_+-V_-)$$
Because the output is connected to the inverting input, you now have:
$$V_{out}=A_0(V_+fV_{out})$$

$V_{out}$ can be less of more than $V_{-}$.But my question is how does Vout does take away or add to the V- to make it equal to V+.

Comment: Have you read "Opamps for everyone" ? Download it for free here: http://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf   An opamp does not add/subtract voltages, it amplifies a **voltage difference**. Solve your 2nd formula: Vout = A0 (Vin - Vout) for a very large value of A0. Result: Vout = Vin.

Comment: It doesn't work for your circuit. Or rather, it will work just fine for op amps which can provide infinite current - which is to say, not. Redraw your circuit with both input and feedback resistors, then see if your question is still valid.

Comment: i am reading from practical electronics for inventors. I am new to electronics. I don't know a good place to learn about op-amp, although the book is very easy to understand.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, what is wrong with the premise of my question.

Comment: @Doeser - In the circuit AS SHOWN the output cannot influence the input (assuming a zero input impedance), since any voltage change requires infinite current. At the same time, the input voltage cannot override the output, for exactly the same reason. Hence, your equation is wrong from one aspect or another.  So insert resistors and reconsider the question.

Answer (score 0):

If and only if the op amp's output voltage \$V_{out}\$ is the **only** voltage source that is driving (connected to) the op amp's inverting input \$V_{-}\$, then via some simple algebraic manipulation of the equation \$V_{out} = A_{0}(V_{+}-V_{-})\$ we have,

$$
V_{out} = A_{0}(V_{+}-V_{-})\\
= A_{0}V_{+}-A_{0}V_{-}\biggr\rvert_{V_{-}=V_{out}} \\
= A_{0}V_{+}-A_{0}V_{out} \\
\Rightarrow V_{out}+A_{0}V_{out}=A_{0}V_{+} \\
\Rightarrow V_{out}(1+A_{0})=A_{0}V_{+} \\
\Rightarrow V_{out}=\frac{A_{0}}{1+A_{0}}V_{+}\biggr\rvert_{A_{0}\gg 1} \\
\Rightarrow V_{out}\approx V_{+}
$$

In this case, \$A_{0}\$ is the op amp's open loop voltage gain. At low frequencies (close to DC) and for a "typical" op amp, \$A_{0}\$'s value might be in the range \$10^{5}-10^{6}\, V/V\$, in which case \$A_{0}\gg1\$ and the approximation result \$V_{out}\approx V_{+}\$ is valid.

Note that if two different voltage sources—e.g., \$V_{X}\$ and \$V_{out}\$—are directly connected to the same circuit node—e.g., the op amp's inverting input terminal \$V_{-}\$, the two voltage sources will fight each other for control of the voltage at that node. At the very least the system will be unstable, and it's quite likely one or both of the voltage sources will eventually fail catastrophically.

Comment: Nope, the output is the only driving voltage. There is a non zero V-. Isn't that the definition of negative feedback.